# Partner users keys using keycloack

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, authorization, keycloak

I have an application that uses keycloack as authorization/authentication. But some partners will embed in their website (using iframes) my application and I need to get the username logged in the partner sites.

Unfortunately the grant_type=client_credentials doesn't suit me because I just need the partner's logged in username.

How can I resolve this issue?

Using the federation approuch is not an option as I have many partners.

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/simZU.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for this issue, your partner will login your application by Access Token.

You need provider information login for partner to get Access Token from your API login then partner login via Access Token with your application.

Login via Access Token, your partner can pass Access Token by query parameter.

Comment: Thanks for answering! But I need to get the username in my JWT, so a client_credentials doesn't serve me.